# In cypress how can I check the response time of an action

Tags: cypress

On clicking a button, I will get a dropdown with a list of items. I want to check how much time it takes for the drop down to come after clicking the button. I want to write a test using cypress for this to check performance. Intention is to check the performance of the app when the item list contains 100 thousands of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

index2.html:

```
<div class="many">
</div>
<button id="manyadd">add many</button>
<script>
var prom = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    var parent = document.querySelector(".many");
    var e = document.createElement("div");
    e.classList.add("red");
    parent.append(e);
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
})
async function createElement() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        await prom();
    }
}
document.querySelector("#manyadd").addEventListener("click", () => createElement());
</script>

<style>
    .red {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

and cypress code:

```
describe("many elements", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit("index2.html");
    })

    it("wait until all elements", () => {
        let t1 = null;
        let t2 = null;

        cy.get("#manyadd").then(b => b.click());
        cy.get(".many > div").then(() => t1 = new Date());
        cy
            .get(".many > div", { timeout: 20000 })
            .should(elements => {
                expect(elements.length).to.eq(10);
                t2 = new Date();
            })
            .then(() => cy.log(`duration: ${(t2.getTime()-t1.getTime())/1000} seconds`))
    })
})
```

The example app code adds 10 div container and the cypress test waits until all are loaded. if you want exact times you may utilize `MutationObserver` but this is definitly more code than in my example :-P

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Josef Biehler.